# Trouble understanding how stack() works

Tags: r

I can't wrap my head around the documentation for [?stack](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/stack.html) and why it's not working.  Consider:

```
> set.seed(1)
> x1 = sample(c(letters[1:5], NA), size=10, replace=TRUE)
> x2 = sample(c(letters[1:5], NA), size=10, replace=TRUE)
> is.vector(x1)
[1] TRUE
> rbind(x1, x2)
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
x1 "b"  "c"  "d"  NA   "b"  NA   NA   "d"  "d"  "a"  
x2 "b"  "b"  "e"  "c"  "e"  "c"  "e"  NA   "c"  "e"  
> stack(x1, x2)
Error in rep.int(names(x), lapply(x, length)) : invalid 'times' value
> stack(list(x1, x2))
Error in rep.int(names(x), lapply(x, length)) : invalid 'times' value
> df = data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2)
> stack(df)
Error in stack.data.frame(df) : no vector columns were selected
```

Here is what I want:

```
values  ind
   "b" "x1"
   "c" "x1"
   "d" "x1"
    NA "x1"

    ... etc.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`x` needs to be a named list:

```
stack(list(x1= x1,x2 = x2))
```

Comment: And not just a list, but a _named_ list (or a data.frame).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich The documentation should probably be clearer about that, I think.

Comment: I agree, but someone's going to come along and say to just use plyr instead, so it's a moot point. :)

Comment: What a weird nuance. So neither of my attempts (e.g., `... list(x1, x2)`) works, but you need to put them together.  Any idea why?

Comment: If there is no name on the lists, then there is nothing to use as the labels for the origin column.

Answer (score 6):

Well, first off you are passing a matrix argument to stack when its help page is asking for: "a list or data frame to be stacked or unstacked." Furthermore if you make it into a dataframe with the default setting for stringsAsFactors it will fail with a very uninformative error message.

```
 d=data.frame( x1=x1,x2=x2) 
 stack( d , select=c(x1,x2) )
#Error in stack.data.frame(x, ...) : no vector columns were selected


 d=data.frame( x1=x1,x2=x2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 stack( d , select=c(x1,x2) )
#----------
   values ind
1       b  x1
2       c  x1
3       d  x1
4    <NA>  x1
5       b  x1
6    <NA>  x1
7    <NA>  x1
8       d  x1
9       d  x1
10      a  x1
11      b  x2
12      b  x2
13      e  x2
14      c  x2
15      e  x2
16      c  x2
17      e  x2
18   <NA>  x2
19      c  x2
20      e  x2
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that permutation as well, & got that error message. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The factor columns cannot be easily stacked because they do not share a levels attribute, so any given number in the internal representation has an ambiguous meaning if you just stacked the raw integers.

Comment: `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` is an important element here. Specially if you are loading your data into R.

Comment: It's possible one may need to do `as.character` to any of the columns involved.